# Optional Filtering on many keys in graphql with different operands

Tags: typescript, graphql

I have a Character type where I want to have some optional filtering based of specified key attributes and linked operands with values. My current problem is that a player should be able to filter the characters, so they can find a character that suits them the most.

I have just started using Graphql and wanted to use the problem as research for making some small projects. At the moment I'm trying to translate some plain MySQL queries to Graphql and have the basics working, but I can't find any multi-filtering options that suits my use case. I hope that someone with more experience with GraphQl can help my with my research.

How the filtering has been setup now within Typescript + MySQL is as following:

```js
async getFilteredData(filter: FilterObject): Promise<Charater[]> {

   let query = "SELECT * FROM Character ";
   if (filter.age && filter.age.value) {
      query += `WHERE age ${filter.age.operand} ${filter.age.value} `;
   }
   ... // And so on for every column in the Character table
   try {
      const filteredCharacters: Characters[] = await getConnection().query(query);
      return filteredCharacters;
   } catch(error) {
      console.log("ERROR_DURING_CHARACTER_FILTERING: ", error);
      return [];
   }
}
```

I have applied stuff to prevent SQL injections and stuff. The example above is just so you understand a little how I have been doing it so far.

Now I tried to translate this in GraphQl and thought I didn't need this whole cumbersome method. But so far I have been searching for examples I can't seem to find any examples that comes close to the use case I have been tumbling on.

Beneath here you can see how i have defined the Character type.

```js
type Query {
  character: [Character]
}

type Character {
  id: ID
  name: String
  age: Int
  cashpile: Float
  bonus: Int
  account_created_on: Int 
  total_earned: Float
  total_spend: Float
  strength: Int
  defence: Int
  healthpoints: Int
  victories: Int
  defeats: Int
}
```

These are the query filters that are used widely when searching for the right character:

```
SELECT * FROM Character
WHERE age > 5
AND total_spend < 10000
AND defence > 10
AND healthpoints> 120
AND defeats < 100
AND victories > 200
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM Character
WHERE age < 10
AND total_spend > 10000
AND defence = 27
AND healthpoints > 180
AND strength > 120
```

or just a simple search like

```
SELECT * FROM Character
WHERE name LIKE "arg%"
```

My iniial tought of Graphql and filtering were like the following example

```js
query {
   Character {
      id
      name
      defence: equal(27)
      strength: greaterThenOrEqual(120)
   }
}
```

I hope that there is something like this. Need some guidance on how other people fix this.

Comment: What are you using for a back end? You would need to implement this functionality in your resolvers on the server.  Some projects like [Graphcool](https://www.graph.cool/) will auto-generate schemas with filtering built in, but it's probably overkill just to filter.  I'd recommend just writing a resolver that executes the exact queries you want.

Comment: I'm using a nodejs backend. and yeah Graphcool looks nice but it is overkill. I'm finding a way for Graphql to filter per specified key if a value has been applied to it, but i guess that was too much asked for.

Comment: While the QL does stand for query language, GraphQL does not replace a database. It will work with any DB, so it cannot automatically interface with whatever you're using to source your data and usually ends up being more complex than a straightforward REST API as you still need to write the queries yourself.  It's the hottest new thing from Facebook, but unless you deal with changing data at a large scale it tends to overcomplicate things, in my opinion.

Comment: GraphQL just turned 4 years old, so I don't know if I'd call it "the hottest from Facebook" but I would agree with @RutherfordWonkington that converting GraphQL queries to SQL queries usually ends up being hairier then you would expect. I would highly recommend looking into existing solutions like Join Monster, Prisma, Hasura or Postgraphile if you're going to tightly couple your API with your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no special syntax needed for what you're trying to do -- it's sufficient to utilize one or more arguments with the appropriate input types. This is how I'm handling it in one project:

```
type Query {
  characters(filter: CharacterFilter!): [Character!]!
}

input CharacterFilter {
  age_eq: Int
  age_not_eq: Int
  age_gt: Int
  age_gte: Int
  age_lt: Int
  age_lte: Int
  age_in: [Int!]
  age_not_in: [Int!]
  name_eq: String
  name_not_eq: String
  name_like: String
  name_not_like: String
  name_iLike: String
  name_not_iLike: String
  name_in: [String!]
  name_not_in: [String!]  
  # and so on for the remaining attributes
  and: [CharacterFilter!]
  or: [CharacterFilter!]
}
```

The recursive `and` and `or` fields give us a lot of flexibility in constructing the underlying SQL. For example, we can write a query like:

```
query {
  characters(filter: {
    name_like: "Bob",
    or: [
      strength_gt: 10,
      and: [
        defense_lte: 20,
        healthpoints_lt: 100
      ],
    ],
  }) {
    id
  }
}
```

This sort of pattern (borrowed from Prisma) is just my preference though. Hasura, for example, uses [a different pattern](https://docs.hasura.io/1.0/graphql/manual/queries/query-filters.html)  that relies on more nested input types. There's any number of other alternative patterns and there's not really an established convention -- it's just a question of what makes sense for your backend and for the clients that will be consuming the API.

Comment: Thank you for the example and response on my question. This looks a little bit like what i wanted to achieve.